# Compila, pero el resultado es erróneo ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: c

```
//programa para sacar el sueldo neto de un trabajador

#include <stdio.h>

int horasTrabajadas; 
int salario;
float sueldoHora = 125.50;
int horaExtra = 251;
float imss = 4.7;
int isr = 3;


int main()
{
    printf("ingrese horas trabajadas: ");
    scanf("%i", &horasTrabajadas);

    salario = horasTrabajadas * sueldoHora + horaExtra - imss - isr;
    printf("el salario del trabajaor es: %i", salario);


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Abel. ¿Podrías indicarnos un ejemplo con los datos que devuelve y cuáles son los datos que esperas?

Comment: ¿Que es exactamente lo que tiene que hacer?¿Cual seria una respuesta correcta y cual una incorrecta? Asi como esta se ve un programa sin muchos problemas

Comment: es en la operacion de salario, me esta sumando las horas extras en automatico y necesito que las sume en caso que el empleado tenga horas extras y si no las tiene que no las sume.  no se si me explico bien.

Comment: Lo más importante aquí es saber: ¿Qué resultados obtienes? Y ¿Cuáles esperas? Sólo así podremos ayudarte como se necesita, tu código fubciona a la perfección, así que el problema no está en tu código, sino en tu lógica, explicanos lo que necesitas lograr editando la pregunta, así te ayudamos mejor :), saludos!

Comment: @AbelCervantes según lo que indicas, debes hacer uso de un `if-else` que permita separar cuando el empleado tiene horas extras y cuando no, y a partir de ahí utilizar tu fórmula para calcular el salario.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta y aclaración son un poco confusas:

Dices:

> necesito que las sume en caso que el empleado tenga horas extras y si
>   no las tiene que no las sume

No hace diferencia que el valor de las horas extras sea 0 o el valor constante que tiene de acuerdo a tu fórmula:

```
int horaExtra = 251;
```

Haría diferencia si por ejemplo fuese un valor negativo, y eso es algo que tendrías que controlar.

El otro problema que veo es que declaras `salario` como entero, y al realizar una operación con flotantes, habrá un truncamiento de precisión décimal.

Comment: Esto es más un comentario que una respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

A primera vista pareciera una operación simple.
**Cosas a tomar en cuenta:**
1. El tipo de dato para tu salario sería mejor si utilizas Double o float, para tener una operación aritmética en números de punto flotante.(Decimales)
2. Utilizar paréntesis, muchas veces puede hacer una diferencia en el resultado, se recomienda cuando haya operaciones de multiplicación o división especialmente.

```
salario = (horasTrabajadas * sueldoHora) + horaExtra - imss - isr;
printf("el salario del trabajaor es: %i", salario);
```

3. La variable horaExtra al ser parte de una suma, no afectará a tus resultados, en caso que sea cero dado qué: 1 + 0 = 1  (el valor cero no afecta a la operación de suma)
4. En caso que imperativamente necesites validar puedes escribir tu código de la siguiente manera, que te asegure a tu variable horaExtra, un valor de cero o mayor:

```
// Asegura que horaExtra no es negativo
horaExtra = (horaExtra < 0) ? 0 : horaExtra; 
salario = (horasTrabajadas * sueldoHora) + horaExtra - imss - isr;
printf("el salario del trabajaor es: %i", salario);
```

Espero sea de ayuda. Un cordial Saludo.

Comment: Dudo mucho que necesite usar decimales para trabajar con valores enteros tan pequeños (te recuerdo que `int` admite valores hasta 2^31) y lo de los paréntesis está bien comentarlo pero no es el origen del problema... la respueta es bastante floja

Comment: @eferion Admite 2^31 pero en ENTEROS no en punto flotante, por lo tanto las operaciones que utilicen números enteros se _redondean_, y eso mas que programación es matemáticas, sus variables algunas definidas como `int` y otras `float` es recomendable utilizar el mismo tipo en operaciones matemáticas, especialmente si requiere precisión, para comprobar: **(3/2) = 1.5** si ambos son variables de punto flotante, caso contrario será **1**,  no veo ningún aporte en tu comentario, podrías ser un poco mas **Constructivo**, espero ver tu respuesta como ejemplo.

Comment: ahora bien, su problema central podría ser el planteamiento de su operación aritmética, si vemos qué, por cada hora laboral está pagando _125.5_ y quiere computar además las horas extra, aunque no se indica que son las demás variables _imss, isr_ su fórmula podría ser del a siguiente manera:  `salario = ((horasTrabajadas + horaExtra) * sueldoHora) - imss - isr;`

Comment: `float` tiene una precisión de 6 dígitos y `double` de 12 o 13, mientras que con `int` tienes una precisión de 30 dígitos. Por otro lado una suma, resta o producto de números enteros resulta **siempre** en otro número entero y ya me gustaría a mi ver una operación de horas trabajadas que requiera un resultado de más de 2^31

Comment: Por otro lado yo no respondo a preguntas que no están bien elaboradas o se antojan incompletas... como es el caso. De hecho si en las próximas horas no se edita la pregunta para que cumpla unos requisitos mínimos empezará a ser votada para su cierre y evitar así que se pueda llenar de respuestas que dificilmente van a dar con la solución (recordemos que la pregunta no indica qué problema tiene, luego dar una solución correcta es complicado sin elucubrar... y yo no soy mago)

Comment: Con el primero de los dos comentarios, que ya no puedo editarlo, quiero decir, sintentizando, que usar `float` o `double` puede llegar a penalizar resultados que requieran de más dígitos significativos de los indicados (6 o 12) y que el ejemplo de la pregunta no justifica su uso. PD.: haz un código que imprima los números del 100.000.000 al 100.000.020 usando `float` a ver que pasa

Comment: Podrías por favor fundamentar tu comentario sobre la precisión de los tipos ? me interesa bastante, 32 bits de espacio en memoria no quiere decir 32 bits de precisión aritmética decimal. (1/3) = 0.333333.... mientras que si la operacion tuviera un entero el resultado sería 0, y esos no son números que pasen a los 32 bits. en todo caso si su intención es manejar números precisos, le recomiendo Binary Coded Decimal (BCD) library. puede encontrar mas información: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx **PD: haz 1/3 con la precisión entera a ver que pasa**